# Where is the API documentation for Mapper.Context in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm having fun coming up to speed with Hadoop, which includes checking out t

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/

The documentation for the class Mapper makes extensive reference to the class Mapper.Context (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context). However, I can't see to find API documentation for that Mapper.Context class/interface/whatever it is except in old versions of the API. Where in the current API would I find documentation for Mapper.Context in particular? I see it being used in various places (context.write method, most commonly), but I can't find current documentation for those methods, despite having spent some time searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a lot of specific documentation it would seem. It would appear the reason for this is that the `Mapper.Context` class is merely an internal `abstract class` that implements the interface [`MapContext`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext.html) and nothing else. See line 106 in [the source code](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html). Since `MapContext` extends [`TaskInputOutputContext`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.7/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskInputOutputContext.java), that's probably the best place to look for good information.